# SoapUI does not change log file name/path after changes in soapui-log4j.xml

Tags: log4j, soapui

I'd like to set different directory for soapui logs so I made some corrections to `soapui-log4j.xml` file:

```
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${soapui.logroot}soapui.log"/>
     <!--param name="File" value="C:\Temp\soapui.log"/-->
     <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="50"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
     </layout>      
   </appender>
```

E.g. simply change the name of the file:

```
<param name="File" value="${soapui.logroot}soapui_1.log"/>
```

Or change path:

```
<param name="File" value="C:\Temp\soapui.log"/>
```

But this does not help, file is not created at all after this changes. Should I change something else?

Comment: Ivan, please see the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SoapUI uses log4j settings file from `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui-xxx.jar` file.
If it is required to override the configurations, pass the system property `soapui.log4j.config` with respective log4j configuration file name as its value.

- Goto SOAPUI_HOME/bin
- Open file SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions in a text editor (file name might differ in case version is different)
- Add a line at the end of current configuration

  `-Dsoapui.log4j.config=/absolute/path/of/log4j.xml`

**NOTE:** Use file path separator in unix style / even on windows. Also use the same style in log4.xml file as well for your customized log file paths.

Comment: This is all correct. +If test is changing file in SOAPUI_HOME/bin/, you should run soapui test with admin rights. But it does not matter for folders that does not require admin rights to create files

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko, glad that helped. Thank your for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

One fix to the logging exceptions is to run SOAPUI in Windows with elevated privileges. But I don't like to do that except as a very last resort.

If you are willing to edit some of the installed files, a better fix comes in two parts. (Rao's answer talks about defining a different configuration file for log4j, but you really only need to define one symbol which then subsequently gets used by log4j).

With a text editor, edit the file in a path similar to this (yes, it's the same file that Rao's answer tells you to edit, but the change is different):

> C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions

and point to your chosen logging folder by adding a line similar to

> -Dsoapui.logroot=C:/Users/Test/.soapuios/logfiles/

I also found that I needed to edit the testrunner.bat, because the test runner doesn't run with the symbols that you've just added to SOAPUI. Using the same installation path as above, for me this is located at:

> C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\testrunner.bat

and you need to add an additional JAVA_OPTS near the end of the file which defines the same symbol that you placed into the .vmoptions file.

Finally, you might also want to edit the file toolrunner.bat (if you ever use those tools)

Answer (score 0):

```
run testrunner in linux 

cd /home/readyapi 

/usr/local/readyapi2.3.0/bin/testrunner.sh  -Dsoapui.log4j.config="/home/readyapi/config/soapui-log4j.xml" -r -a -j -f/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/webapps/report "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -Eautotest "/home/readyapi/project/auto-api-riskcontrol-readyapi" &
```

```
-Dsoapui.log4j.config="/home/readyapi/config/soapui-log4j.xml"  : use custom log4j config
```

```
"/home/readyapi/project/auto-api-riskcontrol-readyapi" : this is a composite project
```

notes:
create folder **"/home/readyapi/scripts"** , put all scripts library 
when run testrunner.sh  cd to folder **"/home/readyapi"** firstly , since testrunner loading scripts library under current folder.